# Knowledge Data Categories in Lightning Knowledge

Tags: lightning, knowledge, lightning-knowledge, data-category

I'm working on a knowledge conversion from classic to lightning. I've migrated a small collection of article types to record types and enabled lightning knowledge. The problem I'm having is related to knowledge data categories - these don't appear when lightning experience is enabled, even when I try to create a new article I'm not given the option to assign it a data category. Doing the same thing in classic gives the option though. I'm finding it difficult to find a clear answer as to whether or not data categories work with lightning knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to edit and add 'Article Data Categories' component to knowledge record page.

[image]

Click down arrow near 'Expand All'. Edit and add data categories.

[image]

Comment: Those options are greyed out for me, and I haven't been able to find out which permissions Im missing. do you know?

Comment: I found out. You can only edit data categories on draft articles, so make sure the article is a draft.